# Mapping data in a grid not working properly Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to map data out in a grid using Chakra UI but the grid renders the grid items in a vertical layout, as opposed to horizontal layout which it should be. What could be the solution?

[image]

```js
import { Avatar, Box, Button, Grid, GridItem, Text, VStack } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ViewApp () => {
return (
 {apps.map(app =>{
    return ( 
     <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={6}>
      <GridItem w="100%" bg="#f5f5f5" borderRadius='lg'>
        <Box as="button">
          <Flex>
           <Box mt={3} ml={6}>
             <Avatar />
           </Box>
           <Box ml={4}>
           <VStack>
            <Box>
             <Text fontSize="sm">
               <SkeletonText isLoaded={!loading}>
                app.product
               </SkeletonText>
              </Text>
             </Box>
             <Box>
              <Text mt={-2} fontSize="lg" fontWeight="bold">
               <SkeletonText isLoaded={!loading}>
                app.displayName
               </SkeletonText>
              </Text>
              <Text fontSize="sm">
               <SkeletonText isLoaded={!loading}>
                app.createdAt
               </SkeletonText>
              </Text>
             </Box>
            </VStack>
            </Box>
           </Flex>
         </Box>
        </GridItem>
      </Grid>
            )
        })}
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the Grid component outside the map function. Like this :

```js
<Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={6}>
        {apps.map(app =>{
        return ( 
                
                <GridItem w="100%" bg="#f5f5f5" borderRadius='lg'>
                  <Box as="button">
                    <Flex>
                      <Box mt={3} ml={6}>
                        <Avatar />
                      </Box>
                      <Box ml={4}>
                        <VStack>
                          <Box>
                            <Text fontSize="sm">
                              <SkeletonText isLoaded={!loading}>
                                app.product
                              </SkeletonText>
                            </Text>
                            ....... </Grid>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).